# command line cURL parameters in PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-authentication

I'm working on a PHP script that has to connect to an REST API. The provider of the API, suggested to use cURL. They gave me an example of how to use it in the command line:

```
curl -D- -u "user:password" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://example.com/api/searchFunction?jql=assignee=user1
```

The PHP script is the following:

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com/api/searchFunction?jql=assignee=user1', 
CURLOPT_USERPWD => "user:password",
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => 'CURLAUTH_BASIC'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, ($defaults));

echo "cURL output: ".curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

 ?>
```

As you can imagine, the command line version works fine, but in the PHP version I got the following error:

```
Field 'assignee' does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users.
```

That suggests that the user login validation doesn't works. However, the user and password are correct.

I was looking for already answered posts of cURL parameters equivalents between the command line version and the PHP version but couldn't find the correct parameters for the PHP version.

Comment: `?jql=assignee=user1 ` - what's that supposed to be? Could there be a typo?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17991852/4815044) perhaps this answer to a similar question might help you.  urlencode the jql variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't fully replicated your cURL command yet.

For starters, you've never set the `Content-Type: application/json` header option.  You need to set that using the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.

Secondly, command line cURL and PHP's cURL use different `User-Agent` values.

Consider enabling the command line cURL's verbose option so you can see all the information it's sending, then replicate it PHP.

Comment: You were right. Adding the -v to the cl script gave me the headers of the request and the response. I was missing this:

    $headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
     'Authorization: Basic AAABBBCCCRandomString'
    );

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers.

 And this works properly without the defined user_agent